# How do I convert this Auth0 rule to action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, action, auth0, rules

As rule is deprecating in near future, I want to convert this rule to action:

```
function (user, context, callback) {

  user.awsRole = 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Auth0v2,arn:aws:iam::1234567890:saml-provider/Auth0';
  user.awsRoleSession = user.name;

  context.samlConfiguration.mappings = {
    'https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role': 'awsRole',
    'https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/RoleSessionName': 'awsRoleSession'
  };

  callback(null, user, context);

}
```

I tried to convert it as following for action:

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
 const user = event.user;
  user.awsRole = 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Auth0v2,arn:aws:iam::1234567890:saml-provider/Auth0';
};
```

However it shows the warning:

```
Property 'awsRole' does not exist on type 'User & { multifactor?: string[] | undefined; } & { identities: UserIdentity[]; }'.(2339)
```